# Creating a button in Javascript for each value generating in the loop

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a data from the back end and I have to create a button for each value generated by that time

This is for a web page and it should display the button for each values i.e. whatever is in `values[i].good and values[i].bad`

```
for (i in values){
  msg += values[i].good + ' - ' + values[i].end+ '<br>';
  $('<button type>',{text:values[i].good + ' - ' + values[i].bad,id : 'btn_'+ i});
}
```

For example, if my data is (12-13,13-14)
if `values[i].good` is 12 and `values[i].bad` is 13,then I need a button (12-13), the same thing should be repeated for all values. All button should display in the web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.setAttribute("id", 'btn_' + i);
```

then put this inside

```
var btn_text = document.createTextNode(values[i].good + ' - ' + values[i].bad);
button.appendChild(btn_text);
```

After that append this to element

```
var element = document.getElementById("div1") //If have wraper
//OR
var element = document.body // If no

//Then Apply
element.appendChild(button);
```

Like this code

```js
var values = [{
  good: 13,
  bad: 14
}, {
  good: 14,
  bad: 15
}, {
  good: 16,
  bad: 17
}];

//element = document.getElementById("div1") //If have wraper
var element = document.body
for (var i in values) {

  var para = document.createElement("button");
  var node = document.createTextNode(values[i].good + ' - ' + values[i].bad);
  para.setAttribute("id", 'btn_' + i);
  para.appendChild(node);
  element.appendChild(para);
}
```

Comment: I want only the button should be displayed.Can you help me how to display the buttons only